# I'm doing leetcode question 64 and I am having trouble with one specific testcase

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python and i have been trying to learn dynamic programming. Hence, I choose this problem.

The question goes like this:

Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right, which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.

Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

Here are some examples:

Input: `grid = [[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]`
Output: 7
Explanation: Because the path 1 → 3 → 1 → 1 → 1 minimizes the sum.

Input: `grid = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`
Output: 12

My code works on the these 2 examples but fails when the input is `[[1,2],[1,1]]`.

Here is my code:

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.res = float("Inf")
    def minPathSum(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        self.path(grid, len(grid) - 1, len(grid[0])- 1, grid[len(grid) - 1][len(grid[0]) - 1])
        return self.res
    
    def path(self, grid, m, n, total):
        if m == n == 0:
            self.res = min(self.res, total)
            return
            
        
        if m != 0:
            return self.path(grid, m - 1, n, total + grid[m-1][n])
        if n != 0:
            return self.path(grid, m, n - 1, total + grid[m][n-1])
```

Comment: Do you understand what the correct solution should be in this test case?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output and your actual output for the testcase you failed?

Comment: Since there are already a given number of ways, you can go with recursion, like `return min(findPath(for_bottom), findPath(for_right))`. This will reduce the time complexity as well to `log(m+n-1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the code using recursion and minimize the time required to `log(m+n)`.

```
class Solution:
    def find_sum(self, start_x, start_y,  end_x, end_y, current_sum=0):
        if (start_x < end_x-1) and (start_y < end_y-1):
            right_sum = current_sum + self.grid[start_x][start_y+1]
            down_sum = current_sum + self.grid[start_x+1][start_y]

            return min(self.find_sum(start_x, start_y+1,  end_x, end_y, right_sum), self.find_sum(start_x+1, start_y,  end_x, end_y, down_sum))
        
        elif start_x < end_x - 1:
            down_sum = current_sum + self.grid[start_x+1][start_y]

            return self.find_sum(start_x+1, start_y,  end_x, end_y, down_sum)

        elif start_y < end_y - 1:
            right_sum = current_sum + self.grid[start_x][start_y+1]

            return self.find_sum(start_x, start_y+1,  end_x, end_y, right_sum)
        
        return current_sum

    def minPathSum(self, grid: list[list[int]]) -> int:
        self.grid = grid
        return self.find_sum(0, 0, len(grid), len(grid[0]), grid[0][0])


print(Solution().minPathSum([[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]))
print(Solution().minPathSum([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))
print(Solution().minPathSum([[1,2],[1,1]]))
```

Output:

```
7
12
3
```

All sample test cases are passing.

Comment: This answer would benefit from elaboration on what exactly you changed. What was wrong with the OP's code? How does this fix it?